# PowerShell one-liner - How to

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Let's have this example PS code:

```
$Secr = $Encrypted | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $Key
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Secr)
$Decrypted = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
```

The variables `$Secr` and `$BSTR` are used just once.

Is it possible to put it into a one-liner to avoid those temporary variables?

I tried to eliminate `$Secr`, but this does not work:

```
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Encrypted | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $Key)
$Decrypted = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
```

Another example is:

```
$GetKey = Get-Content "C:\temp\AESKey.AES.Key"
$Text = "Test Message"
$Encrypted = ConvertTo-SecureString $Text -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString -key $GetKey
```

Is it possible to eliminate `$GetKey` variable?

How to make it work? What is the correct syntax?

Comment: "this does not work" is a pretty vague failure mode description :) What happens? Does it throw an error? Blow up your computer?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Yes, an error occurred, because the system evaluated the pipe with a priority, splitting the command line into two wrong parts.

Comment: the one-liner `[System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new('', (ConvertTo-SecureString 'test' -AsPlainText -Force)).Password`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either the grouping operator `(...)` or the subexpression operator `$(...)` to evaluate your command pipelines in place of the variable expressions:

```
$Decrypted = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto(
  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR(
    ($Encrypted | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (Get-Content "C:\temp\AESKey.AES.Key"))
  )
)
```

(You can remove the linebreaks for a "true oneliner", only introduced for readability)

Same treatment for the second example - simply substitute the variable expression with the appropriate pipelines nested in the `(...)` grouping operator - or, in the case of simpler literal expressions like strings, skip the operator completely:

```
$Encrypted = ConvertTo-SecureString "Test Message" -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString -key (Get-Content "C:\temp\AESKey.AES.Key")
```

See the Special Operators section of the [`about_Operators` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#special-operators) for more information

Comment: When I replace `$Key` in your code (for `$Decrypted`) with `(Get-Content "C:\temp\AESKey.AES.Key")`, the system throws an error. Why?

Comment: Please see https://justpaste.it/986k0

Comment: That's because of the unescaped linebreak after `-Key`. Place the next opening `(` on the same line as `-Key` and it'll work

Comment: I see. Thanks. Is there some specific rule when line-breaks are not allowed? In most, if not all, other programming languages, such a new-line would make no difference.

Comment: In short: any "balanced qualifier" (opening quotation marks, `{`, `(`, `[` etc.) or binary operator token (`-eq`, `-like`, `-lt`, `,`, `|` etc.) can be followed by an unescaped linebreak, since the parser will keep looking for the next token even across linebreaks to "complete" the syntax element.

Comment: You can also put a backtick in front of a linebreak, in order to prevent the linebreak from being parsed.